Write the PCollection periodically in Flink on Beam application
I'm new to Apache Beam and have a question regarding its usage.
I have a scenario where I need to read a stream of elements from a PCollection and write them to a new file every 5 minutes.
Initially, I considered using Timers and state stores, but I discovered that Timers are only applicable to KV pairs. If I convert my PCollection into a key-value pair with a dummy key, I encountered several issues:

It introduces an additional shuffle.
With all elements sharing the same key, they would be processed by a single task in the Flink on Beam application. I prefer not to manually define number of keys based on load because I plan to run multiple pipelines, each with varying loads.

One alternative I considered is using a custom executor thread within my Writer DoFn to flush the records every 5 minutes. However, this approach would require me to use a lock to prevent the process element block from running during the flush.
Is there a more effective way to accomplish this?
